# Which keyboard layout is this?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

[image]

Which keyboard layout is this? Its AZERTY so I tried French (all french keyboards but the keys up are not well mapped) it's really weird.

Comment: I think I've figured it out! This was a fun challenge, thanks :)

Comment: Its my laptop !

Comment: Did you buy this from a Apple store?  Whoever you bought it from owes you an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Tony Tran's answer is almost correct — it *is* in fact the Italian set of keycaps, but the keycaps have been moved around to a custom AZERTY layout!

The combination of characters present in the five keys just to the left of the <kbd>↩︎</kbd> key (and indeed, even any one of those keys) is not found in [any other Mac keyboard layout](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794).

[image: Italian MacBook keyboard]

Comment: So its not a factory keyboarf they edited it ? Also can I find a solution to this layout (to install it?%) thanks

Comment: @YassineBelatar  To be able to type with this you have to create a custom keyboard layout with Ukelele or Karabiner.  Are you sure there is not one already on the machine?  It might be called Italian AZERTY.  Or move the keys back where they belong for standard Italian.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I found from Apple, it's keyboard layout for Italian.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/italian_notebook.png

Comment: The links you provide show a QWERTY keyboard, not AZERTY, and many other keys are very different from the Italian layout as well.